# Dynamic Windows installation for different users

Tags: domain-controller, windows, pxe-boot, wds

I am new in server administarting
also I have one question for all you guys.

Now, I plan to create reintallation system
and I want to ask you 
**if is posible to install specific software for each user or a user goups.**
All users and groups are stored and creted in Domain controler.

For example:
Group or user A in Windows installation progress gets installed some PDF reader
Group or user B in Windows installation progress don't get any PDF reader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to go about this is software assignment/publication via Group Policy, in my opinion.  Then you as the administrator will have complete control over which users and/or groups get what software loaded on their machines.

Comment: With this policy software will be delivered every time user logs in or only over isntallation process?

Comment: It will only be installed as needed. One thing to watch out for is if the software to be installed has prerequisites like .NET 4.0 or something, the software installation will fail until you install the dependencies, at which time the software will be installed automatically. Another thing to watch out for is that sometimes reboots or at least logoffs/logons are required before software can be fully installed.

Comment: It should also be noted that you can only assign or publish msi installers. You can't do it with exe's. For that, consider a startup script that installs the exe from a distribution share or something. There are also third-party group policy extensions for installing software that is not in an msi package.